# HTML Canvas, How do you create a circle at the position of the mouse when clicked and then for the circle to increase in radius?

Tags: html, animation, canvas, geometry

So, I have tried attempting this myself and have searched heavily online and I can't seem to solve this particular issue. I am attempting to make a very simple effect that looks like a very basic water ripple. I intend for the user to be able to click somewhere on the canvas, and for an empty circle (with a black stroke) to appear where the mouse has clicked (starting at a radius of zero), and continuously expand the radius as an animation.

I currently have this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <!-- Search Engine Optimisation (SEO) -->
   <title> Ripple </title>
   <meta description="Codelab assignment 3">
   <meta keywords="Uni, assignment, ripple, interactive, discovery">
   <!-- End of Metadata -->
   <!-- Links -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
   <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1024" height="768" style="border: 1px solid"></canvas>
 </body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
  var canvasHeight = canvas.height;
  var radius = 0;
  
  //Have a rectangle fill the canvas and add a hit region
  //Call the ripple function from the rectangle function
  //Track mouse position in rectangle

  function ripple(e) {
   // ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(e.clientX,e.clientY,radius,0,2*Math.PI);
   //ctx.closePath();
   ctx.stokeStyle = "black";
   ctx.stroke();

   radius++;

   requestAnimationFrame(ripple);
  }

  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', ripple);
 </script>
</html>
```

This is what it currently does:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wx0i5.png)

I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to pass the *mouse event* when calling the `ripple` function through *requestAnimationFrame*.

also, you'll need to set the radius to `0` and clear running animation frame *(if any)*  on mouse click

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
var canvasHeight = canvas.height;
var radius = 0;
var rAF;

function ripple(e) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.stroke();
    radius++;
    rAF = requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        ripple(e);
    });
}
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    if (rAF) cancelAnimationFrame(rAF);
    radius = 0;
    ripple(e);
});
```

```css
body{margin:10px 0 0 0;overflow:hidden}canvas{border:1px solid #ccc}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="635" height="208"></canvas>
```

**note:** use `e.offsetX` and `e.offsetY` to get proper mouse coordinates relative to canvas.